# Angular is changing URL for background.jpg in css

Tags: angular

I have a bunch of asset files in an asset folder. I have different environments that are set up in my angular.json config that successfully move the appropriate background.jpg file to the /assets/ folder. My CSS is set up to point to this:

```
background: url("./assets/background.jpg")
```

but when I serve the project and look at the source, the CSS is somehow now pointing to:

```
background: url("background.jpg")
```

At no point do I have code set up to make this change to the CSS.

Why is this happening and how do I make it stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a relative path for your background image. So when you build your application, Angular puts the file in the root folder and updates the path.

If you want to prevent this, you can either use an absolute path like `/assets/background.jpg` or prefix your path with `^` (`background: url("^./assets/background.jpg")`). In this case the builder will ignore it. In both cases make sure the image is copied to `/assets` when building your application.

Comment: That was very annoying to deal with. I ended up just moving the background image to the root to get it working. I didn't want to use absolute paths because the app doesn't live in the root folder of the site, but the ^ trick worked and I will keep that in mind in the future. Thanks